# What the difference between tf.Graph.add_to_collections and tf.add_to_collections?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my model I used to add the variable to collections as  tf.add_to_collections(['xxx', 'yyy'], val) but now with updated version of tensorflow I see another method tf.Graph.add_to_collections, Whats the difference b/w them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [implementation of `tf.add_to_collections`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L5857-L5874), you will see that it just does:

```
get_default_graph().add_to_collections(names, value)
```

So it is exactly the same as calling `tf.get_default_graph().add_to_collections`. The collections are really associated with a graph, in most cases you are just interested in one graph, which is the default one, but sometimes you may want to manage different [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph) objects manually, and in that case you may prefer to use the methods of the graph class instead of relying on which one is the default one. If you are only working with one graph, though, [`tf.add_to_collections`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_to_collections) is usually more convenient and readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :) . actually my tf.add_to_collections isnt working anymore only tf.add_to_collection works. Has tf.add_to_collections been deprecated ?

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal Not that I know of, in fact [the method `add_to_collections` is based on `add_to_collection`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L3771-L3790), so it should really work. Bear in mind though that in eager mode collections only work with [`EagerVariableStore`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/EagerVariableStore), and in TensorFlow 2.x they will be removed altogether for both graph and eager mode.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I will keep it in mind now. I still need to keep up and learn new features of tensorflow. Its growing so fast that I feel left out :)

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal Glad it helped. Please consider marking the answer as accepted if you feel it solved your question.